# how to add "Phpmyadmin" to laravel sail (docker + laravel) - auto: answer

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, phpmyadmin, laravel-sail

- **This is your docker-compose file**
- to add "Phpmyadmin" you just have to the following commands that I will leave in "answer"

  ## For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail

  ```
    version: "3"
    services:
        laravel.test:
            build:
                context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
                args:
                    WWWGROUP: "${WWWGROUP}"
            image: sail-8.0/app
            ports:
                - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
            environment:
                WWWUSER: "${WWWUSER}"
                LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            volumes:
                - ".:/var/www/html"
            networks:
                - sail
            depends_on:
                - mysql
        mysql:
            image: "mysql:8.0"
            ports:
                - "${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306"
            environment:
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
                MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
                MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
                MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
                MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
            volumes:
                - "sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql"
            networks:
                - sail
            healthcheck:
                test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
                retries: 3
                timeout: 5s

    networks:
        sail:
            driver: bridge
    volumes:
        sailmysql:
            driver: local
  ```
- I hope I have helped, since I realized that there is not much information on this, (at least not clearly)...

Answer (score 8):

because I did not get clear answers to this question in the community, I decided to ask it and answer it.

To add a new docker container in our laravel sail, you must go to **"docker-compose.yaml"** which is in your project folder.

once there copy and paste the following command lines.

```
 phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            PMA_HOST: mysql
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
```

save the file and go to your terminal in the project

PC~/(folder-name)$ :  add " **./vendor/bin/sail up** " -> only what is inside the quotes

***and finish :) If it served you, vote positively for this answer, thank you.***

Comment: Probably worth adding that it is accessed via localhost:8080, might seem obvious, but, you know... thanks